# Understanding what these metric names in Hazelcast mean

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana, hazelcast, payara

Could someone please help me to understand what these metrics mean in a Hazelcast environment and if it is measured in Bytes, Percentage, etc ? I am using Grafana and Prometheus to collect these information from a Payara Server.

com_hazelcast_app_size

com_hazelcast_app_localTotal

com_hazelcast_app_localHeapCost

com_hazelcast_app_localTotalGetLatency

com_hazelcast_app_localTotalPutLatency

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Hazelcast documentation, these attributes come either from maps or multimaps: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.8/manual/html-single/index.html#jmx-api-per-member

The docs don't provide much information. You can find more detailed description in the Hazelcast source code in https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.12.8/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/jmx/MapMBean.java:

- `size` - size of the map
- `localTotal` - the total number of operations on this member
- `localHeapCost` - the total heap cost of map, Near Cache and heap cost
- `localTotalGetLatency` - the total latency of get operations. To get the average latency, divide to number of gets
- `localTotalPutLatency` - the total latency of put operations. To get the average latency, divide to number of puts